# ProviderIncompatibleException with entity framework 4 ctp5 and oracle express

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-4, oracle-xe, entity-framework-ctp5, devart

I encountered a ProviderIncompatibleException when I tried to connect on a Oracle express database with dotConnect for Oracle and entity framework 4 ctp5. I have Oracle Express 10g and I download the trial version for Oracle express today, so I have version number 6.0.86.0 of the dlls

Here's my config. Any idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

We have replied you at our forum [here](http://www.devart.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=20039).
The code sample:
    public class MyOracleContext : DbContext {

```
  public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; } 
  public DbSet<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; } 

  static MyOracleContext() { 

    System.Data.Entity.Database.DbDatabase.SetInitializer<MyOracleContext>(null); 
  } 

  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) { 

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); 

    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.Edm.Db.ColumnTypeCasingConvention>(); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: It seems that the problem was related to the version of dotConnect that I downloaded. It didnt work with dotConnect for Oracle 6.00 Express but it worked with dotConnect for Oracle 6.00 Professional Trial